# Get the previous 8 quarters in an hour, an hour ago

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

What i want to do, is display the last 8 quarters in an hour, one hour ago.

I already have this:

```
<?php
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
?>
```

For example:
Its now 14:46 (2:46 PM), so what i want, is this:

13:45
13:30
13:15
13:00
12:45
12:30
12:15
12:00

How can i get that?

Comment: Looks like you're having some difficulty with the problem solving part, not the programming part.

Comment: If you can't come up with a solution for this on paper, then your difficulty is not with the programming part. You're having difficulties solving the problem and getting the logic out of it so you can program it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$hour = date('G',(time()-(60*60)));
if (date('i') < 15)
    $min = array('00','45','30','15');
elseif (date('i') < 30)
    $min = array('15','00','45','30');
elseif (date('i') < 45)
    $min = array('30','15','00','45');
else
    $min = array('45','30','15','00');
for ($i=0;$i<=8;$i++) {
    if ($min[$i%4] == 45) {
        if ($hour == 0)
            $hour = 23;
        else 
            $hour--;
    }
    echo $hour.':'.$min[$i%4];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Works right now, but I have not tested any further.

Local time: 15:06

Output:

```
14:00
13:45
13:30
13:15
13:00
12:45
12:30
12:15
12:00
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to figure out when the last quarter was. Then it's as easy as going back from there. Here's how I would do it:

```
$minute = idate('i');
$qdiff = $minute % 15;
$lastQuarter = time() - $qdiff*60;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $lastQuarter);
```

Try to figure out what my code is doing. Especially learn how to use the [modulo](http://php.net/modulo) operator since it's very useful for a large set of numeric problems!

Comment: This is not what the question asks for though. The example first rounds down to the previous hour, *then* starts extracting quarters. Upvoters *sigh*.

Comment: Jon, I'm aware that my answer is only half the solution, but it shouldn't be hard to work out the rest from here (which I think is a good exercise).

Answer (score 1):

Or another way to do it, just something i quickly put together:

```
function quarters($date) 
{
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $date->modify("-1 hour");
    $quarters = array()
    for($i = 0; $i<=7; $i++)
    {
        $nearestQuarter =  floor($date->format("i") / 15) * 15;
        if($i == 0)
        {
            $minuteDiff  = (int) $nearestQuarter - $date->format("i");
            $date->modify(sprintf("%s minutes",$minuteDiff));
        }
        else
        {
            $date->modify("-15 minutes");
        }
        $quarters[] = $date->format("H:i"); 
    }
    return $quarters;
}
var_dump(quarters("2011-12-07 14:46:00"));
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "13:45"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "13:30"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "13:15"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "13:00"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "12:45"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "12:30"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "12:15"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest it doesn't need anywhere near so much code to do what you need:

```
$t = time() - 60 * 60;
$t -= $t % (60 * 15);

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++, $t -= (60 * 15)) {
  echo date('H:i', $t), "\n";
}
```